# Jquery storage / toggle class order of operations

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I am very new to Jquery and somewhat new to HTML.  I am working through some training examples on W3 but I need some more insight.

I have a Status section which contains a list of items and divs.  The div is a colored box which is default to green.

```
<h2>STATUS</h2>
    <ul>
        <li>Device 1
            <a href="mailto:email@webhost.com" onClick="alert('You are about to change the status of this device.')"><div id="State1" class="Sgreen"></div></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

There are a total of 8 devices.  I have a css class to toggle to red when the div#State1 is clicked using Jquery.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#State1").click(function(){
            $("#State1").toggleClass("Sred");
        });
    });
</script>
```

What I need to happen when someone clicks the div#State1:

1. Alert window:  Text = You are about to change the device status
2. Email Window:  They need to send the email to support before the toggleClass takes place.  If they cancel out of the email window, the toggle class doesn't happen.
3. The class for the div#State1 needs to be stored so that every time the site is refreshed or closed and reopened again on any computer, the div#State1 class is the most recent class that was used.

The 2 classes I have for the toggleClass are "Green" or "Red" color changes.  Red meaning the device is down, green meaning it is up.

I have the toggle working, but not saving the date on reload/refresh, it defaults to green because that is what I have the class set to in html.

I can get the alert to open and the email to open, but I am unsure of how to go about getting all of these things working together like I need them and saving the last class used.

Any direction to a tutorial, guide or even an example would be most helpful.

I don't want a handout because I do want to learn how to do this.  I just need a little help along the way.

Thanks!

Comment: Still looking for assistance here if anyone has the time to help out.

Maybe this is a PHP question?  I don't know PHP but am looking into it.  I just finished a basic training course on JavaScript and my brain is fried and am a little lost.

Comment: `Email Window: They need to send the email to support before the toggleClass takes place. If they cancel out of the email window, the toggle class doesn't happen.`. I don't know if you can do that, when you click a `href="mailto:..."` anchor, the default e-mail client opens(Per example outlook), and you have no control of it.

Comment: `The class for the div#State1 needs to be stored so that every time the site is refreshed or closed and reopened again on any computer, the div#State1 class is the most recent class that was used.` Cookies are the way for this. Google may be your ally.

Comment: So maybe instead of using an href to mailto I could just use a form with a cancel or submit button and if the user hits cancel nothing happens else the status changes. I could put that all in code correct?

Comment: I'll look into the cookie solution. Thank you!